# Referencing JOIN columns within a subquery from an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to reference columns in JOIN tables of a subquery from an aggregate function, as follows:

```
WITH my_activities AS 
   (SELECT activities.*, owner.* 
    FROM "activities" 
    INNER JOIN relationships AS owner 
        ON activities.owner_id = owner.person_id) 
SELECT owner_id, json_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', owner.id)) AS data 
from my_activities 
GROUP BY owner_id
```

This approach results in:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "owner"
```

I've tried a bunch of approaches to this, with no luck:

Referencing 'my_activities.owner.id' in the json_build_object instead of just 'owner.id' results in the same error.

My goal here is to end up with groups, where each group contains the Activity record and all of the 'relationships' records that are associated with it. I'll then create a FeedActivity record referencing the Activity record, and storing all the related Relationships in a data column.

Ideas?

Comment: what is `ActiveRecord::`? Please tag appropiately.

Comment: The relation on which you are aggregating is called `my_activities`, not `owner`.

Comment: Why are you even using a CTE (or "subquery") here? It would work fine without.

Comment: @Bergi - 1) I updated the post with my reason/goal, 2) Referencing 'my_activities.owner' results in same error.

Comment: Not `my_activities.owner.id`, just `my_activities.id`. (This assumes that `activities.*, owner.*` does not produce a conflict of multiple columns named `id`)

Comment: @Bergi it does produce a conflict

Comment: Then give it a proper alias by replacing `activities.*, owner.*` with `activities.owner_id AS …, owner.id AS …` and using those aliases in the outer query on `my_activities`

Comment: @Bergi okay, thanks. Do you think there's a simpler way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Sure, get rid of the CTE entirely and just write `SELECT activities.owner_id, json_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', owner.id)) AS data FROM activities INNER JOIN relationships AS owner ON activities.owner_id = owner.person_id GROUP BY activities.owner_id`

Answer (score 0):

The cte you use has its own name (my_activities), so the subsequent select statement can only refer to that name. It is no longer possible, through the cte, to refer back to the original tables.

```
WITH my_activities
AS (
    SELECT activities.*
        , owners.*
    FROM activities
    INNER JOIN relationships AS owners ON activities.owner_id = owners.person_id
    )
SELECT my_activities.owner_id
    , json_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', my_activities.id)) AS data
FROM my_activities
GROUP BY my_activities.owner_id
```

nb: although "owner" is a non-reserved word in postgres I would avoid using it if for no other reason than to avoid confusion.

The other thing to avoid is over-reliance on those asterix. Way better to literally specify the columns you need - and only the columns you need. e.g.

```
WITH my_activities
AS (
    SELECT activities.owner_id
        , owners.id
    FROM activities
    INNER JOIN relationships AS owners ON activities.owner_id = owners.person_id
    )
SELECT my_activities.owner_id
    , json_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', my_activities.id)) AS data
FROM my_activities
GROUP BY my_activities.owner_id
```

**However** in the query as provided there really is no benefit at all in using a cte, and if you did it in a more traditional manner then you would refer to the original tables:

```
SELECT activities.owner_id
    , json_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', owners.id)) AS data
FROM activities
INNER JOIN relationships AS owners ON activities.owner_id = owners.person_id
GROUP BY activities.owner_id
```